# getSharedPreferences() always return first SharedPreferences object when I get SharedPreferences that located in difference application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to use an application to read same preference from 2 or more applications.

The first application(`com.ex.sp1`) writes a string `No.1` to its shared preference `myPref`.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
preferences.edit().putString("name", "No.1").commit();
```

The second application(`com.ex.sp2`) writes a string `No.2` to its shared preference `myPref`.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
preferences.edit().putString("name", "No.2").commit();
```

The third application gets the preference from 1 and 2 then show the string on activity.

```
TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);

Context sp1Context = createPackageContext("com.ex.sp1", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
SharedPreferences preferences = sp1Context.getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
String sp1Text = preferences.getString("name", "Orz");

Context sp2Context = createPackageContext("com.ex.sp2", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
preferences = sp2Context.getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
String sp2Text = preferences.getString("name", "Orz");
myText.setText(sp1Text + "   " + sp2Text);
```

The expected string should be `No.1   No.2`, but the result is `No.1   No.1`.

If I change the preferences file name to different like `myPref1` `myPref2`..., then the result is correct.

Anybody have same experience, or have a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: You are overwritting your name. Aren`t you?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the second sharedpreferences in a different SharedPreferences object, maybe it's not overwriting it

Comment: I tried, got same result. I also tried to get second SharedPreferences in other method, then I got "No.1" again.

Comment: If you're using eclipse, open the DDMS perspective and in the file explorer, go to data/data/com.ex.sp1 and data/data/com.ex.sp2, pull both sharedpreferences files and check if they're being created and set correctly

Comment: I've used adb shell to check these files. They have created and set correctly. Also, in the third application, if I read preference from com.ex.sp2 then read from com.ex.sp1, then the result is "No.2 No.2". Seems android only check the preferences file name, then gave the cached file :(.